# Is there any way to create a desktop shortcut on Windows CE?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, windows-ce

I have created an App for WinCE and I was wondering if there is any way to create a shortcut to the .exe file from the Desktop. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean in the operating system or with an installer? Did you try dragging the executable while holding CTRL+SHIFT?

Comment: I can't hold CTRL+SHIFT because it's a handheld device and has only a numeric keyboard, so to press CTRL you have two press two buttons in two separate states.

Comment: See what appears to be [official info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861519.aspx) on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to ***manually*** create a shortcut file (.lnk) using Notepad, by counting the total number of characters in the path to your .exe file (including spaces and slashes), then the content in the file should be like this:

`(total number of characters)#(path to exe file)`

Then you would save it.

For complete information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861519.aspx

Comment: Thanks. At first didn't work because I had an extra empty line at the end, but then I deleted the empty line and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but here is some code to help (thank you @Keanu73):

```
public static void AddAppShortcutToDesktop()
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"\Windows\Desktop\My New Shortcut.lnk", false, Encoding.UTF8, 4096))
    {
        var appExeFilePath = "<Path to Exe>"; // \Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe
        sw.Write(appExeFilePath.Length);
        sw.Write("#");
        sw.Write("\"" + appExeFilePath + "\"");
    }
}
```